# React JS and FAstAPI Athentification errors Cors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors

Hi I made an API with fastapi! The authentication is based on JWT and I can't use it on my website made in React JS! I specify that it works locally and that I am a python developer !
When I put my API online the authentication blocks with a CORS error! Someone can help me !?
[image]

I made an Api with a proxy in the REACT project ("proxy": "https://www.api.zoneanimee.com/") with JTW authentication! All other URLs work! Finally those which are not subjected to the restriction of the authentication! So I want to have a solution related to the CORS error!
Here is my request for the login in REACT JS :

```
const submitLogin = async () => {
        if (email === "" && password === "") {
            setEmailError("Email is required")
            setPwdError('Password is required')
        } else if (email === "") {
            setPwdError('')
            setEmailError("Email is required")
        } else if (password === "") {
            setEmailError('')
            setPwdError('Password is required')
        } else {
            setEmailError('')
            setPwdError('')
            const requestOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                // withCredentials: true,  
                // crossorigin: true,  
                // mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(
                    `grant_type=&username=${email}&password=${password}&scope=&client_id=&client_secret=`
                )
            }

            const response = await fetch("api/login", requestOptions)
            await response.json()
                .then(res => {
                    // if (!response.ok) {
                    //     steErrorMessage(res.detail)
                        console.log(res)
                    // } else {
                    //     setToken(res.access_token)
                    //     steErrorMessage('')

                    // }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

First thing I would check - if https://www.api.zoneanimee.com/api/login is returning header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Based on error looks like it is not doing that. So make the endpoint return such header.

You might find more detailed information here: https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/16/how-to-debug-cors/

Comment: In my answer below, I put a picture of what I am sending back! This is an API developed with python and I used AuthO2 for authentication!

Comment: It does not matter with what it is developed. It has to return a header I think. Google how to return header in python from python code or from server.

Comment: I have found the solution for a while now! But thanks for helping me!